# What happens in the brain that allows access to a previous unavailable memory?

Tags: neuroscience, memory

What happens in the brain that allows you access to a memory previous unavailable?

For example I forgot the name of someone I've known for years. Two weeks later, without notice, "Diana" popped up.

Why was it not accessible when I found I couldn't remember?

What was the chemistry that occurred that allowed it to happen later?

(Secondarily, is this the same breakdown in dementia and alzheimer's? That is, a breakdown of the 'search memory' mechanism? Or is that the memories themselves are 'losing coherence.')

Answer (score 5):

These kinds of research questions are interesting, but notoriously hard to investigate empirically, because:

1. You need human subjects that are able to provide complex feedback, *i.e.*, you can't use invasive, long-term recordings in animals;
2. You need subjects to undergo long-term experiments, as your example indicates in the order of weeks, for *one single measurement*;
3. You need subjects that experience this regularly and frequently;
4. You need a way of faithfully time-stamping the exact moment of recall and somehow establish a procedure to grasp what's happening inside the brain against a variable, uncontrolled background.

In essence, it's next to impossible to find out.

There is, however, a large body of literature around memory recall in general, including detailed imaging studies, *e.g.*, [Heckers *et al*. (1999)](https://jamanetwork.com/journals/jamapsychiatry/fullarticle/205540), [Hall *et al*. (2001)](http://www.jneurosci.org/content/21/6/2186.short), [Liu *et al*. (2012)](https://www.nature.com/articles/nature11028) and I'm sure there will be much overlap between spontaneous and deliberate memory recall.

<sub>**References**

**-** [Heckers *et al*. *Arch Gen Psychiatry* (1999); **56**(12): 1117-23)](https://jamanetwork.com/journals/jamapsychiatry/fullarticle/205540)

**-** [Hall *et al*. *J Neurosci* (2001); **21**(6): 2186-93](http://www.jneurosci.org/content/21/6/2186.short)

**-** [Liu *et al*. *Nature* (2012); **484**: 381–5](https://www.nature.com/articles/nature11028)</sub>

Comment: This specific phenomenon has been studied more than I feel this answer reveals, but I'll have to spend some time to collect research if I'm going to post a reasonable counter answer.

Comment: @BryanKrause I'll await your answer!